# how to format a UTC time string using howardhinnant's c++ date library

Tags: c++, date, c++-chrono

Can someone help me to format a date string using Howard Hinnant's excellent [date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).  I am trying to output a UTC date from the current time.  The desired format of the date/time is zulu time per:

"2018-11-01T15:32:56Z" - i.e. "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ"  -

So far using Howard's [documentation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#duration_io) I was able to get the partial result to work as follows:

```
const auto today = floor<days>(system_clock::now());
auto dateTimeString = std::format("{}T{:02}:{:02}:{:02}Z", today, 15, 20, 59);
```

I had to hard code the HH MM & SS fields.  I am sure there is an easy way to format a custom date/time in this library.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `std::format`, then you're using C++20, instead of [Howard Hinnant's date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).  Though the latter is the basis of the C++20 chrono library.

Your code should look like:

```
const auto today = floor<seconds>(system_clock::now());
auto dateTimeString = std::format("{:%FT%T}Z", today);
```

The variable `today` contains a UTC time point with a precision of seconds.  Then `{:%FT%T}` formats the YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS part of it (`%F` for the date and `%T` for the time).